# Updates and extensions not showing up in Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have been asked about the cause of lack of IntelliSense in a Visual Studio installation and the reason was simply that there was no language support installed for CSS and Javascript. However, I told the person to search for "CSS" after clicking on Tools -> Updates and Extensions. It turned out it was not among the menu items. I would like to add it. How to do so?